# Differentiate between Billing and Shipping party

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-connect

In XC 9.0.2, is there a way to differentiate between a "billing" party and a "shipping" party when adding a party to a customer?   the `Party` class doesn't have a way to do this.

I see that `CustomerParty` has a `PartyType` which seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but not exactly clear on how to associate a `Party` with a `CustomerParty`, etc.

`CommerceCustomer.Parties` is also a `List<CustomerParty>`, but that doesn't hold any actual address info.